# Why do I keep getting a “cannot connect to X server error”?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, video, x-server, camera

I am using the FLIR camera with my Raspberry Pi and running it on a Raspbian destro of linux. I've followed the instructions on the Github page perfectly when trying to setup the `raspberrypi_video` files. Everything worked fine but when I attempted to run the program with `sudo ./raspberrypi_video` command I just get an error that says `raspberrypi_video: cannot connect to X server error`

What server are they talking about and why do I need a server to work with a camera?

I've checked to make sure that my pins are set up properly and I've done all the necessary `apt-get` commands so I have no idea why this is happening. Anyone on here have a clue?

GitHub [Repo](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/raspberrypi_video).

Spark Fun Hookup [Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/flir-lepton-hookup-guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the local graphics servers. Just run the command `xhost +local:root` and it should work. Also keep in mind that you will have to run this command every time you restart your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3):

Debian and many other Gnu/Linux distros use X11+Gnu+Linux.

The X11 server handles the screen/keyboard/mouse, your process is trying to connect to it, so that it can display stuff. This normally works without problem, but because you have changed user, it is having trouble authenticating. (There is security between user process and X11 display server, as it is possible to connect over a network — mouse/keyboard/screen here, and program running on the computer over there.)

**Use `kdesudo` or `gksudo`, they give a popup password prompt and will handle the conection between root and your display.**

Comment: Thanks for the response, but `kdesduo` told me that the commmand was not found and `gksudo` tells me `Locale not supported by C library`.

Comment: Can you show, what you did and errors in the question.

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse “Locale not supported by C library” is a problem with your settings that will affect many other programs. You can use `LC_ALL=C gksudo` to force a bare-bones English locale but you should fix that loacle issue.